# How to deal with external console application programmatically? (Windows)

Tags: windows, winapi, console

I like to launch an external console application ("ABC.exe") from within a C/C++ program ("XYZ.exe"). The two will interact with each other. When everything is done, I like to close down the console application. How do I do that? How do I keep or find the handle for it? What windows APIs do I need? Thanks

Comment: Does abc.exe need to interact with the user or can it run entirely on its own without user input?

Comment: Hard to guess what "interact with each other" is supposed to mean.  We live in the Internet age, it isn't rocket science anymore.  I guess.

Comment: ABC.exe will be on its own once launched and will be shut down by XYZ.exe.  My question for now is NOT about the interaction part but how to launch and shut down ABC.exe. For launching, I search and find several options: WinExec, shellexecute and CreateProcess. But for shutting down, I guess I need some way to find the handle of ABC.exe and emit some command. I am not quit sure how to do it.

Comment: There is no single universal way to shut down applications.  Presumably the person who programmed ABC.exe included a way to shut it down, you have to follow those rules.  (Or just terminate it via TerminateProcess.)

Answer (score 0):

A console app interacts using its STDIN and STDOUT, and STDERR handles.  When your app launches ABC.exe, it can redirect those handles so it can write data to ABC's STDIN and read from ABC's STDOUT/STDERR.  MSDN has an article explaining exactly how to do that:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)